# How to detect the number of <p> elements stored in my db?

Tags: php, html

Let's say that I have this text my db.

```
<P>word1</P>
<P>word2</P>
<P>word3</P>
<P>word4</P>
```

How I can detect the number of `<p>` elements after I get my text from my db?

Thanks

Comment: I will give my upvote to the answer doing this with a DOM parser instead of mindlessly counting occurrences of `<p>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Simple HTML DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) for PHP to parse the contents of the text, select all 'p' elements, then count the size of the resulting array.

Comment: This is the only way to go. DOM-based [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) should make selecting all `<p>` tags dead easy

Answer (score 0):

[DOMXpath](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) should put you in the right direction

Answer (score -1):

```
    $text = "<P>word1</P>
<P>word2</P>
<P>word3</P>
<P>word4</P>
";
    $pieces = explode("<p>" , $text);
    echo $pTagCount = count($pieces) - 1;
```

$pTagCount will contain total number of

tags

Comment: This will not catch both `<p>` and `<P>`; it will not catch `<p class='classname'>`; it will wrongly catch occurrences of `<p>` in comments.